# @apply from Gridsome's Tailwind plugin does not work

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, gridsome

I want to use Tailwinds apply feature in my Gridsome project. But error gets thrown that css classes from tailwind cannot be found.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create new Gridsome project

2) Install tailwind plugin
[Github page](https://github.com/brandonpittman/gridsome-plugin-tailwindcss)
[Npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridsome-plugin-tailwindcss)

3) Create css file in assets folder and import in main.js

```
import "~/assets/style.css"
```

4) Create css class in css file

5) Use @apply in css with tailwind component

Nothing happens... css file is properly imported bacause normal css gets applied
Some elements like rounded seem too work but others like bg-blue-500 dont.

Comment: It looks like only simple utitlity classes can be used with apply
https://github.com/tailwindcss/custom-forms/issues/12

Comment: So bg-blue-500 should work too but this errors too hmm...

Comment: Another finding: bg_custom_color defined in tailwind.config,js dont throw error and style gets applied

Comment: I'm able to use @apply in both main.css and within the `<style>` tag in my vue files. I do have to add `@apply` to each declaration to avoid a syntax error in vscode, but it works. Maybe a config issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can figure out, there seems to be a disconnect with Tailwind's documented behavior and its actual behavior.

As per the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components#extracting-css-components-with-apply) on extracting components using `@apply`:

> ..Classes like this should be added directly after the @tailwind components directive to avoid specificity issues.

In practice this results in a main `style.css` file which looks like the following:

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

// Note: you could also just add a custom CSS file here. 
.btn-blue {
  @apply bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}
.btn-blue:hover {
  @apply bg-blue-700;
}

@tailwind utilities;
```

In reality, however, this always throws a build error, and for a totally logical reason. Tailwind injects the `utilities` file with classes derived from the `tailwind.config.js` file.

CSS is compiled linearly, so `bg-blue-700` doesn't exist for reference via apply until `utilities` is imported and read through.

Even though the documentation advises against it, moving component classes *after* `utilities` resolves the compile error:

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

// Note: you could also just add a custom CSS file here. 
.btn-blue {
  @apply bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}
.btn-blue:hover {
  @apply bg-blue-700;
}
```

Not ideal, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: The answer says put components after utilities but the code says otherwise .. I couldn't make an edit to correct it

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components#extracting-css-components-with-apply), wrap it in @layers components {} to prevent unwanted behavior

like this:

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

@layers components {
    // Note: you could also just add a custom CSS file here. 
    .btn-blue {
      @apply bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
    }
    .btn-blue:hover {
      @apply bg-blue-700;
    }
}
```